# Add +/- increment counter to bootstrap selectpicker dropdown

Tags: python, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to add +/- increment counter to a selectpicker dropdown menu instead of just having a checkbox. I'm starting to think this might *not* be possible inside of a selectpicker.
Please be kind, front end is not my strong suit. Here's what I tried which clearly doesn't work and even if it did, it def wouldn't override the default checkbox so that'd look weird.

I'd accept an answer that just says, *this isn't possible* you'll need to forget using bootstrap and do the whole thing in html/js/css.

Here's what I tried which clearly will not work.

```
    <select name='ingredients' class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
        {% for ingredient in ingredients %}
            <option data-content="<input type='number' id='quantity' name='quantity' min='1' max='5'"> {{  ingredient.name  }}  </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

Comment: You should put the `<input>` between `<option>` and `</option>`. Two additions: `id` and `name` should not repeat and your tag is not even closed.

Comment: @KlausD. Yeah I just noticed it's not closing the <option> correctly after my edit. Funny thing is that it got me closer to what I want. lol

Comment: @KlausD. Looking at the documentation for custom content, it looks like putting the input inside the first option tag is the way to do it. [link](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/)